# To create map link in android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I want to generate map link and want send mail of that link. when user will click on that link map should be opened in the browser with that location.I have generated the link and also it shows the location but problem is it does not shows the pin for current location.How to modify the link so that i can get the pin on map. The link which i have generated is as follows,

https://www.google.com/maps/preview/@"+latitude+","+longitude+",16z

Comment: how can it "lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem" when a useable and accepted answer has already been given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=latitude&mlon=longitude#map=zoom/latitude/longitude
where mlat and mlon specifiy the position of the marker.

Comment: Perfect solution getting exact result

Answer (score 0):

Create a GIF image containing a pushpin (called pushpin) and copy it into the res/drawable-mdpi
folder of the existing project

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public classLBSActivity extendsMapActivity {

MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
private classMapOverlay extendscom.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
@Override
public booleandraw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
booleanshadow, longwhen)
{
super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
//---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---Point screenPts = newPoint();
mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
//---add the marker---FIGURE 9-10
Displaying Maps
❘ 367
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);
return true;
}
}
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public voidonCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView= (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setSatellite(true);
mapView.setTraffic(true);
mc= mapView.getController();
String coordinates[] = {“1.352566007”, “103.78921587”};
doublelat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
doublelng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
p= newGeoPoint(
(int) (lat * 1E6),
(int) (lng * 1E6));
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(13);
//---Add a location marker---MapOverlay mapOverlay = newMapOverlay();
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
}
public booleanonKeyDown(intkeyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
//...
}
@Override
protected booleanisRouteDisplayed() {
//...
}
}
```